# How to hide GUI when mouse is over?

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey, show-hide, mouseover

I create an simple overlaying GUI:

```
Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption
```

Sometimes there are buttons behind it, and I want the GUI to hide when mouse is over, so that I can see and click buttons behind it. When the mouse in not over anymore, the GUI shows again.

I really can't google out a simple solution for this. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adapting what Lexikos did with the mouse hook to monitor whether your mouse is hovering over the position where your GUI is/was. There may be more efficient solutions (which I would also like to see), but this will definitely work.

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/27067-mouse-move-detection/

Here's the example code snippet in case link gets broken:

```
#Persistent
MouseHook := DllCall("SetWindowsHookEx", "int", 14  ; WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
    , "uint", RegisterCallback("MouseProc"), "uint", 0, "uint", 0)
return

MouseProc(nCode, wParam, lParam)
{
    global MouseHook
    Critical
    if wParam = 0x200 ; WM_MOUSEMOVE
    {
        ToolTip % NumGet(lParam+0,0,"int") ", " NumGet(lParam+4,0,"int")
    }
    return DllCall("CallNextHookEx", "uint", MouseHook
                    , "int", nCode, "uint", wParam, "uint", lParam)
}
```

Comment: is there a way to use it properly? I put it in my script and the gui simply disappears. My mouse always has a tooltip showing its coordination wherever it is.

Comment: @Ooker This is just an example of how to use the mousehook. In your case, you would need to check against known coordinates (your GUI position plus size) instead of making a tooltip and act accordingly (`Gui, Hide` or `Gui, Show`).